# Swipe left/right to push next/previous details view

Tags: ios, storyboard, pushviewcontroller, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am working on a ios application, using storyboard.

I have a simple table view with rows. Each row has a "key" string to identify it. When the user clicks on a row I push the next view "DetailsViewController" and pass the "key" as a parameter in the `prepareForSegue` method. The data in the second view will change based on the "key" passed.

In the "DetailsViewController" I want to add a swipe gesture, when the user swipes right, I want to push the next details view. It will be as if he clicked on the next row in the table view. So to rephrase, the user has 2 ways of switching between items: he can click the item in the table view and the details view will show, he can then go back and select another item.

Or he can click on a row, and in the details view he can swipe left and right to see the previous/next item.

i added the uigesture recognizer:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer;
recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
[recognizer setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];

- (void) handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) sender 
{
     //I want to go to the next item in the tableview
}
```

I hope I was clear.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you store the keys in an array named keyarray, you should add an NSIndexpath to save the currently selected row.

In your `handleswipe` method, increment the indexpath by 1, get the corresponding key from the `keyarray` & reload your view.